# Why word "draft" appear center of the page?

Tags: fancyhdr

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{header1}
\rhead{header2}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

in the center of page "DRAFT" appears, how can i erease it? it will appear when i use fancyhdr , but there is no code about it i think =\

Comment: Your Example has no `\begin{document}` nor it contains any text. Please mind that without text some editors (e.g. TeXShop) won't output anything and simply keep the content of the preview window as it was the last time something was output.

Comment: Remove package `background` or  use `\usepackage[pages=some]{background}` or `\usepackage[content={}]{background}`. See the package documentation.

Comment: When posting code, highlight the block and use the `{}` button or `ctrl+k`. This will indent it by 4 spaces to correctly format it. Only use back ticks for short phrases in the middle of non-code text.

Comment: I've rolled back to the previous edit. You just need the example posted to show the problem.

Comment: @esdd I think you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Please stop editing the question. It's fine exactly as it is with the small document posted. And @esdd 's comment will answer it.